# multiple images upload in Django

Tags: html, django

I have two models and two different forms. Tow forms are combined in a single view function. The two forms are combined in a single HTML form. Everything is working fine when I submit the HTML form except the images are not saved. 
Here  are the tow models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_category = models.ForeignKey(Post_Category, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    post_detail = models.TextField(max_length=65536)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s %s %s " % (
            self.user, self.post_category, self.post_title, 
            self.post_detail)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"


class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True )


    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.post, self.images)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "images"
```

the forms are:

```
class PostsForm(forms.ModelForm):


class Meta:
    model = Posts

    fields = [
            'post_category', 
            'post_title', 'post_detail', 

        ]

class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(ImagesForm , self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        self.fields['car_images'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'image',
            'style':'display:none','id':'input-image-hidden',
            'onchange':"document.getElementById('image-preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" ,
            'type':'file', "name":"images", 'accept':'image/*'})

    class Meta:
        model = Images

        fields = [
            'images',
        ]


        widgets = {

            'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

Here is the view function:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def post(request):
    form = PostsForm()
    imagesForm = ImagesForm()

    template_name = 'path/to/template.html'

    success_url = 'user_profile.html'

    form = PostsForm(request.POST or None)
    imagesForm = ImagesForm(request.POST or None, 
    request.FILES or None)

    if form.is_valid() and imagesForm.is_valid():
        new_post = form.save(commit=False)
        new_post.user = request.user 


        new_post = form.save()


        imagesForm.save(commit=False)

        for file in request.FILES.getlist('images'):

            instance = Images(
            post= Posts.objects.get("images"),
            images=file
        )

            instance.save()
        return redirect('index')

    else:
        imagesForm = ImagesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or 
None)
    return render(request, template_name, {'imagesForm': imagesForm, 
'form': form})
```

When the HTML form is submitted, all data are saved except the images( no error pups up).the HTML form is displayed again rather than redirect to the user profile page. 
Can you please advise me to what is going on and where is the possible error or errors. Can you help me to save multiple images

NOTE: USING inline formset factory is not possible if I have to set extra parameter. I do not want to limit user to upload limited numbers of images.

Comment: Maybe this is a misindentation but if you `return redirect('index')` in your forloop your form stops after the first image.

Comment: you are right. This is just misindentation. I correct it. However, problem is still persisting. any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you provide a `print(file)`output. Maybe this helps.

Comment: I am using sublime3. Can you please advice me where to find print(file) result?

Comment: simply put it in the forloop where you are trying to save your files, right after initialising the for loop. The results will show up in your server's terminal/console